# Collision of soliton pulses in nerves

Tags: biomedical-engineering

Consider the collision of two soliton pulses propagating with identical amplitude, equal velocity
in two opposite directions on a nerve. Assume that the collision is head, reversible and adiabatic. Consider the presence of viscous friction in the system. Then the pulses pass through each other almost undisturbed with the generation of some small amplitude noise.

Now, How can I prove this mathematically or in any other way?

Forgive me if this is not the right place to ask this question. If it is not, please tell me where to ask this question.

Comment: Do you really mean on a nerve? Solitons are a particular solution to a particular wave equation model. And they usually appear in a 2D oriented plane. In odd numbered dimensions, such as 3D or 1D, wave equation solutions have completely different characteristics. For instance, all the energy is concentrated in the wave front in odd-dimensioned domains, but it is dispersed throughout an expanding region in even-dimensioned domains.

Comment: Nerves are not a continuous medium. Furthermore nerve signals are not fully analog. There's firing thresholds and other mechanics to take into account, therefore I doubt you will be able to model a nerve impulse accurately as a propagating wave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no clue what you are referring to in biology terms.

But we know in general two waves passing by each other regardless of it being straight head-on or some angle, interfere with each other (with the exception of photons which pass through each other most of the time).

The waves magnify or cancel each other depending on the individual phase at the interaction point. They are called constructive interference and destructive interference.

## constructive Interference

[image: constructive]

## Destructive interference.

.

[image: destructive]